# Why is my bootstrap Javascript not working (wordpress)

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress

Here is my functions php

```
function maxprofessional_scripts() {
    wp_enqueue_style( 'maxprofessional-style', get_stylesheet_uri(), array(), _S_VERSION );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'maxprofessional-main', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/main.css' );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'bootstrap-icons', 'https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-icons@1.5.0/font/bootstrap-icons.css' );


    wp_style_add_data( 'maxprofessional-style', 'rtl', 'replace' );
    wp_register_script('app-js', get_template_directory_uri() . '/app.js', false, '1.0', true);
    // wp_enqueue_script( 'app-js' );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'my_custom_script', get_template_directory_uri() . '/app.js' );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'bootstrap-popper', 'https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@popperjs/core@2.10.2/dist/umd/popper.min.js' );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'bootstrap-jdelivery', 'https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js' );

    

    wp_enqueue_script( 'maxprofessional-navigation', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/navigation.js', array(), _S_VERSION, true );

    if ( is_singular() && comments_open() && get_option( 'thread_comments' ) ) {
        wp_enqueue_script( 'comment-reply' );
    }
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'maxprofessional_scripts' );
```

How i know it is not working is because of the carousel which code is below(The carousel is not working)

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-12">
        <div class="carousel slide multi-item-carousel" id="theCarousel">
          <div class="carousel-inner">
            <div class="item active">
              <div class="col-xs-4"><a href="#1"><img src="http://placehold.it/300/f44336/000000" class="img-responsive"></a></div>
            </div>
            <div class="item">
              <div class="col-xs-4"><a href="#1"><img src="http://placehold.it/300/e91e63/000000" class="img-responsive"></a></div>
            </div>
            <div class="item">
              <div class="col-xs-4"><a href="#1"><img src="http://placehold.it/300/9c27b0/000000" class="img-responsive"></a></div>
            </div>
            <div class="item">
              <div class="col-xs-4"><a href="#1"><img src="http://placehold.it/300/673ab7/000000" class="img-responsive"></a></div>
            </div>
            <div class="item">
              <div class="col-xs-4"><a href="#1"><img src="http://placehold.it/300/4caf50/000000" class="img-responsive"></a></div>
            </div>
            <div class="item">
              <div class="col-xs-4"><a href="#1"><img src="http://placehold.it/300/8bc34a/000000" class="img-responsive"></a></div>
            </div>
            <!-- add  more items here -->
            <!-- Example item start:  -->
            
            <div class="item">
              <div class="col-xs-4"><a href="#1"><img src="http://placehold.it/300/8bc34a/000000" class="img-responsive"></a></div>
            </div>
            
            <!--  Example item end -->
          </div>
          <a class="left carousel-control" href="#theCarousel" data-slide="prev"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></i></a>
          <a class="right carousel-control" href="#theCarousel" data-slide="next"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></i></a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

And here is the JS

```
$('.multi-item-carousel .item').each(function(){
  var next = $(this).next();
  if (!next.length) {
    next = $(this).siblings(':first');
  }
  next.children(':first-child').clone().appendTo($(this));
  
  if (next.next().length>0) {
    next.next().children(':first-child').clone().appendTo($(this));
  } else {
    $(this).siblings(':first').children(':first-child').clone().appendTo($(this));
  }
});
```

Is there something I am doing wrong during the importation of bootstrap js in my functions.php ? I would appreciate the help a lot . Thank you . Is it that i need to register it before enqueue ? I am so lost to why it is not working

Comment: i suggest saving your files locally and not loading the externally

Comment: Did you define $ as jQuery?

Comment: @HowardE Nope , i just put it in the app.js file

Comment: Dont you get any error in developer tool ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bootstrap 5 and over uses **data-bs-slide-to** and carousel-item class, the codes in your question is old codes for bootstrap 4 and less versions.

Here is the link for [latest version carousel](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.1/components/carousel/)

And your working codes :

```js
$('.multi-item-carousel .carousel-item').each(function(){
      var next = $(this).next();
      if (!next.length) {
        next = $(this).siblings(':first');
      }
      next.children(':first-child').clone().appendTo($(this));
      
      if (next.next().length>0) {
        next.next().children(':first-child').clone().appendTo($(this));
      } else {
        $(this).siblings(':first').children(':first-child').clone().appendTo($(this));
      }
    });
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-/xUj+3OJU5yExlq6GSYGSHk7tPXikynS7ogEvDej/m4="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="carousel slide multi-item-carousel" id="theCarousel" data-bs-ride="carousel">
              <div class="carousel-inner">
                <div class="carousel-item active">
                  <div class="col-xs-4"><a href="#1"><img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2016/10/07/13/57/puzzle-1721619__340.jpg" class="img-responsive"></a></div>
                </div>
                <div class="carousel-item">
                  <div class="col-xs-4"><a href="#1"><img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2016/10/07/13/57/puzzle-1721619__340.jpg" class="img-responsive"></a></div>
                </div>
                <div class="carousel-item">
                  <div class="col-xs-4"><a href="#1"><img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2016/10/07/13/57/puzzle-1721619__340.jpg" class="img-responsive"></a></div>
                </div>
                <div class="carousel-item">
                  <div class="col-xs-4"><a href="#1"><img src="http://placehold.it/300/673ab7/000000" class="img-responsive"></a></div>
                </div>
                <div class="carousel-item">
                  <div class="col-xs-4"><a href="#1"><img src="http://placehold.it/300/4caf50/000000" class="img-responsive"></a></div>
                </div>
                <div class="carousel-item">
                  <div class="col-xs-4"><a href="#1"><img src="http://placehold.it/300/8bc34a/000000" class="img-responsive"></a></div>
                </div>
                <!-- add  more items here -->
                <!-- Example item start:  -->
                
                <div class="carousel-item">
                  <div class="col-xs-4"><a href="#1"><img src="http://placehold.it/300/8bc34a/000000" class="img-responsive"></a></div>
                </div>
                
                <!--  Example item end -->
              </div>
              <a class="left carousel-control" href="#theCarousel" data-bs-slide="prev"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></i></a>
              <a class="right carousel-control" href="#theCarousel" data-bs-slide="next"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></i></a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
```